# Jquery or Javascript tracing for events and other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I have many Javascript or jQuery methods in my ASP.net project. 85%+ is client side scripting. I have Jquery validate and Labelify plugins. Hence, whenever I make changes in Jquery methods or Javascript if something fails it is failing in the scriptresource.axd file and not allowing me to submit form. So I would like to have some error log or tracing so that I can log which function is passed and where it is failing.

So,

1. Is there any built in Jquery or Javascript method that does this log or Tracing.
2. If there is no built in please suggest me how to do that in easier way. Right now I thought like this to have `Log(event,startOrEnd,isPassed);` and call this method for each and every event triggering. But I have around 30+ methods so I don't think its a good idea to do this way.

Please suggest a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use firebug or use Chrome's console:

Then you can use all the `console` methods.

**[List of all the methods](http://davidwalsh.name/firebug-console-log)**

---

Shortcut function for `console.log`

```
function log(){
    console.log.apply(console,arguments);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/RuURG/

Comment: They are all already there for you if you are using firebug or chrome console. just start using them

Comment: i have firebug but thing is i am adding console.Log() in all methods do we have any shortcut..?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is, it's simply `console.log()` and you'll see it in the browsers with JavaScript console.

**JavaScript console** is available in **Google Chrome, Apple Safari, IE9, Mozilla Firefox 4 (Tools>Web Console)** or earlier version of FireFox with FireBug extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firebug, you can use the `console.log` function.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarklet on this page:

[jQuery event tracer](http://www.kupio.com/github.com/izb/jQuery-event-tracer/bookmarklet.html)

will log jQuery events for the page you are viewing to the console.